# How to apply Swift constraints on imageView on rotation in code?

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint

The following elegant code derived from the new text by Vandad Nahavandipoor on Swift works fine in landscape however since the scrollView is constructed by code one cannot use usual constraints to properly display the chart named CrossTalk.png in landscape. In fact in landscape the chart initially displays in 50% of the screen and when dragged to the right in an attempt to fill the screen the initiating viewController-1 that segued into the current, displaying viewController-2 takes over the entire landscape view. Is there a way to fix this problem in code?

SWIFT latest version 6.1

```
import UIKit

class ChartViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {    

    var imageView: UIImageView?
    var scrollView: UIScrollView?
    let image = UIImage(named: "CrossTalk.png")


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)

        if let theScrollView = scrollView{
            theScrollView.addSubview(imageView!)
            theScrollView.contentSize = imageView!.bounds.size

            view.addSubview(theScrollView)

   }

}
```

Comment: If the view is created in code, shouldn't you just create the constraints in code as well? Just search for `UILayoutConstraints` in the docs and you should be able to make it work

Comment: I would turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` and then refer to [Auto Layout Guide: Working with Auto Layout Programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH11-SW1), with special focus on the VFL renditions which can simplify the process.